# Error Detection Production Line Using AI/ML

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am new to AI/ML field and I need to solve the following problem using python language.

Basically, I have certain parameters that come in order and I would like to use supervised techniques to discover the error.

I would like to figure out the error in the production process that has a sequential paradigm as follows.

Product ID, Product type, Category type, Product Line, Result (Good, Bad).

Let's say the system takes the following training dataset

```
Product ID, Product type, Category type, Product Line, Result (Good, Bad).
ID1, PT, CT, [L1,L2], Good
ID2, PT, CT, [L1,L2], Good
ID3, PT, CT, [L1,L2], Good
```

And the given test dataset is

```
ID4, PT, CT, [L1,L3], Bad
```

What are the AI/ML techniques that can detect the reason of getting "Bad", which is L3 product line? Also, can I add this new data to the training set to predict the reason of the error later? How can it be implemented in Python?

Comment: Do you want your algorithm to tell you that your result is bad or do you want it to tell you that your result is bad *because* of an L3 problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this works fine, but you may have a look at the *inverse classification problem*.